# What does “in fiocchi” mean in a French text?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, italien

So I was attempting to read *Les Liaisons dangereuses* by Pierre Choderlos de Laclos. And I came across this passage in the first paragraph:

> J’ai pourtant vu plus de parures dans cette seule journée que dans les quatre ans que nous avons passés ensemble, & je crois que la superbe Tanville aura plus de chagrin à ma première visite, où je compte bien la demander, qu’elle n’a cru nous en faire toutes les fois qu’elle est venue nous voir dans son **in fiocchi**.

I understand the passage to mean something along the lines of:

> I had yet seen more finery in this day alone than the four years that we had spent together, and I believe that the suburb Tanville will be more upset at my first visit, when I will ask for her, then she had ever thought to be to us, when she used to come see us in **in fiocchi**.

I looked up the italian meaning, and according to the sources I found it means "flakes" like for cereal. Or "Ribbons". I don't understand what this could mean in context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Être in fiocchi"* is an expression meaning, "Être en grand costume" (similar to, *in ceremonial dress*).

Edit: The 'definition' of the term is

> être en [costume d'apparat](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiocchi), porter tous ses atours

"Costume d'apparat" implies "ceremonial dress", while "porter tous ses atours" is "in full finery".

(credits to jlliagre)

Comment: En costume d'apparat. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiocchi

Answer (score 1):

The young lady speaking in letter was living in a convent, I believe, and would perhaps be wearing some sort of garment for that reason. Thus they used term you asked about....
?